# Russel Peters Intro video

Tags: video, video-editor

I am sorry if this is not the correct place to ask the question.

I am very much interested in making a video similar to youtube link below

Its of Russel Peters intro video, I wanted to know what are such videos called and are there any softwares that can used to make such video.
I am planning to use it in a video to introduce characters in a movie(home video).
The basic idea is to film the characters separately each with different custom and edit it then merge all the characters to look something similar to the video, can any tell me how to go ahead with such a video?
What are such videos called and if there are any softwares to do it.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is no specific title for this kind of video.

You can achieve what you want with any video editor that supports layers and masks. Adobe After Effects would be on solution.